# Can't export blender model to .FBX

Tags: .fbx

I recently made a Tank in blender and i went to export it,there's problem that make i couldnt export,can anybody help to solve this problem? ( I use blender 2.93.4)[image]

[image]

Comment: Try running this from the text editor: https://developer.blender.org/T79775#1016390